# function pointer to methods of different classes

Tags: c++, class

I have a graph class `Graph` and two classes `Pqueue1` and `Pqueue2` of priority queues. Both priority queues have constructors of the form `Pqueuei(Graph &g)` where `i` = `1`,`2` and both of them have a method `Dijkstra` which is of the form : `void Dijkstra(Node*)`. The shortest path tree is written into `g`.

Now I want to write a function that constructs of the two types of priority queues depending on some condition (the density of `g`) and then call the associated `Dijkstra` method.

How can this be done?

I thought about a function pointer `dijk` but since both are methods of a class I need to call them differently, either `pq1.*dijk` or `pq2.*dijk` (where `pq1` is an object of type `Pqueue1` etc.). But then I would have to construct both priority queues in advance which is suboptimal.

Comment: And how would that be related to C? Don't spam tags! And your question is too broad. We are no consulting/tutoring site.

Comment: You need both classes to derive from a common base class, and make the dijkstra method virtual. There is no need to involve function pointers.

Comment: This is a typical problem solved by polymorphism: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Comment: It sounds a bit odd that a priority queue would have Dijkstra's method in its interface.

Comment: @ebyrob Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common approaches: runtime polymorphism and compile-time polymorphism.

For runtime polymorphism, define a base class with a virtual function:

```
class queue_base {
public:
    virtual void Dijkstra(Node*) = 0;
};
```

then derive each of your queue classes from that:

```
class Pqueue1 : public queue_base {
public:
    void Dijkstra(Node*);
};
```

and similarly for `Pqueue2`.

Now objects of those types can be addressed through a pointer to the base type:

```
Pqueue1 q1;
Pqueue2 q2;
queue_base* qp = &q1;
qp->Dijkstra();
qp = &q2;
qp->Dijkstra();
```

For compile-time polymorphism, write a template function:

```
template <class Q>
void do_dijkstra(Q& q, Node* n) {
    q.Dijkstra(n);
}
```

You can call this function with objects of any type that has a function named `Dijkstra` that takes one argument of type `Node*`:

```
Pqueue1 q1;
Node node;
do_dijkstra(q1, &node);
Pqueue2 q2;
do_dijkstra(q2, &node);
```

Comment: To only construct one queue in the first example, `queue_base *qp = cond ? new Pqueue1 : new Pqueue2; ... delete qp;` but this also requires `queue_base` to have a virtual destructor.